# How to get the Base Url in Twig

Tags: node.js, twig

I am using twig in Node+express. How can I get the base url in twig file ? 
I've tried the following 2 snippets:

```
{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost ~ app.request.requestUri }}
```

```
{{path()}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the baseUrl attribute

```
{{ app.request.baseUrl }}
```

usually used with the scheme and host:

```
{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost ~ app.request.baseUrl }}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

I think npm `twig` package haven't any base URL common method(I have checked) so you need to pass it from your `controller` or `route` as per the following.

*Route(route.js)*

```
router.get('/twig', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.twig', {
        message: "Hello World",
        baseUrl: req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl
    });
});
```

*views/index.twig*

```
Base URL : <b>{{ baseUrl }}</b>
```

Comment: Yes its working . Is there any predefined variable or function in twig to do so ?

Comment: I have checked all files of `twig` package but there is no common function and predefined variable. Thanks!